# c - printf("%s") prints an additional @

Tags: c, printf, cs50

I am right know working on the cs50 programming tutorial. Here I should crack a DES-encrypted string.

First I concentrate on the creating a 64bit big array with all possible chars used in the salt.

In the next step, I throw this into two for loops to print out all possible combinations of those two for loops. And that's where I am at right now.

For debug reasons, I did just print it out with `printf("%s",salt)`. Salt is defined as char `salt[2]`. But for some reason, it always prints out `xx@` (`xx` changes every time as expected, I have no idea where the `@` is coming from).

First I thought it might overshoot the array for some weird reason and grab the `@` from random memory. This is why I copied it from my online IDE into my local XCode. Still the same `@` symbol. And now I am confused from where the `@` is coming from.

[Link to my code.](https://www.pastebucket.com/558079)

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define _XOPEN_SOURCE       // DES - implementation
#include <unistd.h>

// shorthands
#define cypher argv[1]

#define ascii_dot 46
#define ascii_slash 47
#define ascii_zero 48
#define ascii_nine 57
#define salt_size 64

#define majA 65
#define majZ 90

#define minA 97
#define minZ 122

int main(int argc, string argv[]) {
    // Checking input
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("<usage>\n<./crack <password_hash>");
        return 1;
    }

    // Create a salter
    // 2 * 26 for letters + 10 for numbers + dot and slash = 64 = salt_size
    char salt_crystal[salt_size];

    {   // Own scope to not waste space for salt_iterator
        int salt_iterator = 0; // used to create salt crystals

        //minuscels
        for (int i = minA; i <= minZ; i++)
            salt_crystal[salt_iterator++] = (char)i;
        //majuscels
        for (int i = majA; i <= majZ; i++)
            salt_crystal[salt_iterator++] = (char)i;
        //ascii_dot to 9
        for (int i = ascii_dot; i <= ascii_nine; i++)
            salt_crystal[salt_iterator++] = (char) i;
    }

    // make the salt and forward it to the next function 
    for (int i = 0, l = salt_size; i < l; i++) {
        char salt[2];
        salt[0] = salt_crystal[i];
        for (int i2 = 0, l2 = salt_size; i2 < l2; i2++) {
            salt[1] = salt_crystal[i2];
            printf("%s ", salt); // DEBUG
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code.

Comment: `salt` is not a NUL-terminated string, you're reading uninitialized memory. `printf("%c%c", salt[0], salt[1]);` should do the job.

Comment: @AndreaBiondo Add your answer as an answer, not a comment! I would upvote.

Comment: 1) Don't assume a specific character encoding without need. 2) What is the problem using _character-constants_ like `'0'`? Don't use magic numbers means not to use them if there is a better (and more standard) way.

Comment: @Olaf Do you mean I should have used this `for (int i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; i++)`? The reason I didn't is that I did not know I could have :) I will change it. Or is there still another way you refer to when you mention a better and more standard way?

Comment: BTW, it's good that you edited to show code, but next time you're doing so try to follow the rules at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- building a **minimal** example with the smallest possible code that produces the same behavior.

Comment: @TheCommoner282: And the rest! If you didn't know, you should first work through a C book. They will all cover such basics. Note you are expected to have at least such basic knowledge asking here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have not posted any code, but I'm guessing you did not null terminate the array you pass to `printf()`...

**EDIT** Good guess:  You set 2 characters into `char salt[2]` and pass that to `printf`. `printf` prints those and continues to read characters from memory beyond the end of the `salt` array until it finds a `'\0'` byte that ends the string.

There are different ways to fix this:

- you can make the array longer and set a `'\0'` after the characters:

  ```
  char salt[3];
  ...
  salt[2] = '\0';
  printf("%s", salt);
  ```
- you can use a precision value of `2` in the `printf` format to print at most `2` bytes from the array:

  ```
  printf("%.2s", salt);
  ```
- you can print individual bytes from the array:

  ```
  putchar(salt[0]);
  putchar(salt[1]);
  ```

As to why you consistently get an `@`, there is no definite answer because you are experiencing undefined behavior, so anything can happen... Note however that `@` has value `64` which is the value you store into local variable `l`. It is possible that the `salt` array is positioned in memory juste before the `l` variable. In little endian, the value 64 is stored in the first byte of `l`.

Also note that the name `l` is not recommended for a variable because it is difficult to distinguish from the number `1` in a fixed font such as this.

Comment: It works. Thank you a lot. Still have to wait a few minutes before I can give you the best answer. Still, I am confused why it was an @ symbol every time a tried it in two different environments. Any idea about that?

Comment: @TheCommoner282 it is not worth trying to work out the result of undefined behaviour unless it has caused a side effect, which on fixing has now gone away, but satisfactorily explains why there was not *another* bug causing the secondary problem.

Comment: @chqrlie That makes a lot of sense. Great explanation. Thanks :)

Comment: @TheCommoner282, in terms of having undefined behavior appear to be consistent, in this kind of case it often depends on what's left on the stack by other functions called before this one; thus, if you move to a platform with a different alignment or change your calling convention there can be variance.